# Javascript button click trigger keypress and add text into input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input class="foo" type="text" />
<button>click</button>

$('button').click(function(){
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 65; // Character 'A'
    $('.foo').trigger(e);   
});
```

I try to trigger a keyboard event and add text into input text.

for some reason, I cant use `= html or text()`, I must trigger keyboard event

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: input has `value` (or in jQueryland where things have to be different, just for the sake of being different, `val` ) - not `text` or `html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY like this : **[String.fromCharCode(e.which)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)**  .Add to the input use with `$(element).val()` .No need to use trigger event .simply load data to element. its enough.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 65; // Character 'A'
    $('.foo').val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="foo" type="text" />
<button>click</button>
```

**Another answer for `contentEditable`**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 65; // Character 'A'
    $('.foo').text(String.fromCharCode(e.which));   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" contentEditable="true" ></div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: This won't trigger keypress event :

Comment: also no need of creating event object also